# What's the lifetime of the object returned by typeid operator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

If I call `typeid` and retrieve the address of returned `type_info`:

```
const type_info* info = &( typeid( Something ) );
```

what's the lifetime of the object returned by `typeid` and how long will the pointer to that object remain valid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

However the implementation implements them, the results of `typeid` expressions are lvalues and the lifetime of the objects that those lvalues refer to must last until the end of the program.

From ISO/IEC 14882:2003 5.2.8 [expr.typeid]:

> The result of a `typeid` expression is an lvalue [...] The lifetime of the object referred to by the lvalue extends to the end of the program.

Answer (score 5):

From 5.2.8.1 of C++ 2003 standard:

> The result of a typeid expression is an lvalue of static type const
>   std::type_info (18.5.1) and dynamic type const std::type_info or const
>   name where name is an implementation-defined class derived from
>   std::type_info which preserves the behavior described in 18.5.1.61)
>   ***The lifetime of the object referred to by the lvalue extends to the
>   end of the program***. Whether or not the destructor is called for the
>   type_info object at the end of the program is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

Its lifetime is the duration of the program. And no matter how many times you write `typeid(x)`, it will return the same `type_info` object everytime, for same type.

That is,

```
 T x, y;
 const type_info & xinfo = typeid(x);
 const type_info & yinfo = typeid(y);
```

The references `xinfo` and `yinfo` both refer to the same object. So try printing the address to verify it:

```
 cout << &xinfo << endl; //printing the address
 cout << &yinfo << endl; //printing the address
```

Output:

```
0x80489c0
0x80489c0
```

Note: for your run, the address might be different from the above, but whatever it is, it will be same!

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/jO4CO

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `static` object. The implementation could create the objects needed by `typeid` expressions dynamically. They only thing that is required is that their lifetime extends to the end of the program. Their destructor doesn't have to be called.

Comment: "And no matter how many times you write typeid(x), it will return the same type_info object everytime, for same type." I don't think that's true, do you have a quote?

Comment: Throw in shared libraries. If a shared library gets unloaded it can make existing pointers to typeinfo objects invalid. I once spent a day debugging exactly this scenario.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: correct. `operator==` should be used to compare to `type_info` instances, not address comparison, which is guaranteed to return true "if the two values describe the same type".

Comment: @Maxim: that's a bit special though, because the Standard says nothing about shared libraries :) Note that you'd get the same effect with a function or a global object.